# APScheduler `add_job()` `next_run_time` values

Tags: python, apscheduler

I'm enqueuing a couple of Jobs, using `BackgroundScheduler` and `add_job`, based on config values.

Primarily the jobs will run based on `crontab` string.

But they may also run once at program startup with a configured delay.

For the former I'm using `trigger=CronTrigger.from_crontab(cron_tab)`.

For the latter, I want to use `next_run_time`, using `.datetime.now() + timedelta(x)`

When both configs are defined this all seems fine and happy. But I want to be able to set my config values to `None` to *not* do those things....

---

The [docs for `next_run_time`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job) say:

> (pass `None` to add the job as paused)

**What does that mean?**

Does that just mean "there won't be a dedicated initial run ... it'll just wait for the next time the cron arrives"? Or does it mean "this will create a disabled job which will never run at all?"

---

And I can't find any docs about `None` in `trigger` or `CronTrigger.from_crontab()` can I pass `None` into either of those to cause the job to just run once (based on the `next_run_time` and then never again?

Comment: Happy to split into 2 questions if anyone wants me to, but they were sufficiently similar that it didn't seem worth it - there's more text in common than in the questions.